# searchBarCancelButtonClicked function isn't being called

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

**Problem**

If I press the *Cancel* button when the searchbar is active (i.e. the blinking typing-indicator and keyboard are showing) the *searchBarCancelButtonClicked* function is run and "Cancel Pressed" is printed.

However, if the *Cancel* button is pressed when the searchBar is not active (i.e. no typing indicator, and no keyboard showing) the *searchBarCancelButtonClicked* function IS NOT called. Rather, the *searchBarTextDidBeginEditing* function is called.

**Questions**

1) Is this normal behaviour?
2) How would I change this so that the *searchBarCancelButtonClicked* function is run even when the searchBar is not active (first responder)?

**Note**

I am not using the UISearchController, only the UISearchBar and UISearchBarDelegate functions.

**Code**

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        self.searchBarHeader.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    }

    searchActive = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    print("Cancel Pressed")
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        self.searchBarHeader.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    searchBarHeader.text = ""
    searchActive = false
    filteredStopArray = []
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    filteredStopArray = stopArray.filter(
    { (dict) -> Bool in

        let nameString: NSString = dict["Name"]! as NSString
        let range = nameString.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the cancel button will receive events only when the  search bar is first responder. When the search bar is not first responder, any touches within the Search bar will make it the first responder and present the keboard.

Comment: @RohanBhale Do you know of any way to make it so that the searchBarCancelButtonClicked function is called even when the search bar is not first responder?

Comment: @JordaW Its not recommended but you can call cancel button tapped from searchBarTextDidBeginEditing by some twisted logic